# I have range of values, I want to count how many of 10% their value is greater than a 13.5

Tags: google-sheets, counting, countif

Below Image show a column of data, a cell having a value to be compared with 10% of values in the range A1:A8

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this formula...

```
=sumproduct(A1:A8*0.1>=C2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
=COUNTIF(ARRAYFORMULA(A1:A8*0.1>=C2),"TRUE")
```

Comment: Awesome!! Thank you!!